How can I create a function in python that takes an object, modifies the location of it and other objects using CustomTkinter?
I am creating an app that lets you choose exercises and basically what I've been trying to do is create a function that takes the ".grid" element and for the exercise chosen and moves the column to 1, and for all other objects in column 2 up a row. The object I am trying to move is self.bench_press.
self.exframe = Tk.CTkFrame(master=self.tabview.tab("Workout Builder"), width=400, height=100, fg_color="#333333")
    self.exframe.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=4, sticky="nsew")
    self.exframe.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)

self.scrollable_frame = Tk.CTkScrollableFrame(master=self.exframe, label_text="Your Exercises                                                                                               Choose Exercises", width=1000, height=500, fg_color="#333333")
    self.scrollable_frame.grid(row=1, column=5, sticky="nsew")
    self.scrollable_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    self.bench_press_pic = Tk.CTkImage(light_image=Image.open("images/bench-press.png"), dark_image=Image.open("images/bench-press.png"), size=(175, 175))
    self.bench_press = Tk.CTkButton(master=self.scrollable_frame, image=self.bench_press_pic, text="Barbell Bench Press", fg_color="#333333", text_color="white", font=Tk.CTkFont(size=26, weight="bold"), hover_color="#444444", corner_radius=38)
    self.bench_press.grid(row=1, column=2)

I've tried creating a function that takes the exercise name as the parameter and then runs the .grid line of code inside of the function. That just gave an error.
def addExercise(exercise):
    column, row = 1, 1
    exercise.grid(column=column, row=row)


always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

maybe first you have to use grid_forget() to remove object from grid without destroing it. And if you put it in cell which already has item then it may need to move it to next cell - so it may also need to use grid_forget and later use grid in next cell, etc.

maybe it would be simpler to keep objects on list, and move object to the beginning of list and later remove (forget) all elements and create all of them again using list of elements.

problem can be if you want to move from one frame to another because it would need to change parent.

@furas You don't have to call grid_forget() before putting something in a new location or before destroying it.

If you want to move buttons in the same frame then you may keep buttons on list to keep order.
exercises = []

And button would have function which send itself to function
item = tk.Button(frame, text=f"...")
item.grid(column=i, row=0)

item['command'] = (lambda x=item:move_to_beginning(x))  # send button to function

exercises.append(item)

And function could move item on list to first place
def move_to_beginning(item):
    exercises.remove(item)
    exercises.insert(0, item)

    recreate_items()

And other function could use grid() to put all elements again - using order from list exercises
def recreate_items():
    for i, item in enumerate(exercises):
        item.grid(column=i, row=0)


Minimal working code in tkinter
import tkinter as tk
        
# --- functions ---

def move_to_beginning(item):
    exercises.remove(item)
    exercises.insert(0, item)
    recreate_items()
    
def recreate_items():
    #for item in exercises:
    #    item.grid_forget()
    for i, item in enumerate(exercises):
        item.grid(column=i, row=0)
      
# --- main ---

exercises = []

root = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

for i in range(10):
    item = tk.Button(frame, text=f"{i+1:02}")
    item['command'] = lambda x=item:move_to_beginning(x)  # send button to function
    item.grid(column=i, row=0)
    exercises.append(item)

root.mainloop()   


Other example which uses bind() to

move to the beginning when left mouse button is pressed
move to the end when right mouse button is pressed

Bind sends even with event.widget so it doesn't need to use lambda to send button.
import tkinter as tk
        
# --- functions ---

def move_to_end(event):
    item = event.widget
    exercises.remove(item)     # remove from list
    exercises.append(item)     # add at the end
    
    recreate_items()

def move_to_beginning(event):
    item = event.widget
    exercises.remove(item)     # remove from list
    exercises.insert(0, item)  # add at the beginning
    
    recreate_items()
    
def recreate_items():
    for i, item in enumerate(exercises):
        item.grid(column=i, row=0)
      
# --- main ---

exercises = []

root = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

for i in range(10):
    item = tk.Button(frame, text=f"{i+1:02}")

    item.bind('<Button-1>', move_to_beginning)
    # <Button-2> = middle mouse button
    item.bind('<Button-3>', move_to_end)
    #item.bind('<Button-4>', move_to_beginning)  # mouse wheel scroll up
    #item.bind('<Button-5>', move_to_end)        # mouse wheel scroll down

    
    item.grid(column=i, row=0)
    exercises.append(item)

root.mainloop()   

You may add new button in any place on list execises using .insert(position, ...) and run recreate_items() to get it in this place in window.

If you just want to move other items below the selected exercise by one row up, then update addExercise() as below:
def addExercise(self, exercise):
    # save current grid information of selected exercise
    info = exercise.grid_info()
    # move the selected exercise to cell (1, 1)
    exercise.grid(column=1, row=1)
    exercise.tkraise()
    # move other exercises below selected one up a row
    max_rows = exercise.master.grid_size()[-1] # get max. number of rows
    for row in range(info["row"]+1, max_rows):
        item = exercise.master.grid_slaves(row=row, column=info["column"])
        if item:   # item is a list
            # move item one row up
            item[0].grid(row=row-1, column=info["column"])

